# change md-tabs button height

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, github-pages

I want to change my tab button to be small/thinner. and I go through the DOM for all of the pointers for the css such as:

```
md-tabs-canvas.md-center-tabs{
height: 10px;
}
md-tabs-wrapper{height: 10px;}
md-pagination-wrapper{height: 3px;}
```

but I can't got the height I want.
Or something I need to do with the `ng-isolate-scope` CSS like rearranges the proposition of this pointer?

## update

This is code from code pen
http://codepen.io/tom031/pen/EZZweq

This is code in production https://tom031.github.io/

Comment: post HTML code as well

Comment: @NagaveerGowda updated code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updates:**

I tried to change the padding of *md-tab-item* on your GitHub page, and it works.
See it in the screenshot: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIc83.png). It is the padding of md-tab-item that makes the elements bigger.

Change the css to this:

```
md-pagination-wrapper {
    height: 30px;
}
md-tab-item {
    padding: 5px !important;
}
```

Comment: well, it seem to work with codepen but not work with my GitHub pages

Comment: I guess you may forget the keyword "!important", or it should work. See in my updates. And you can use F12 in your browser, hover on the related elements, and change the height/width/padding/margin of each element concerned. Then you could find which element's css is decisive to your case.

Comment: thanks so much, I'll take your advice and feedback on here soon :)

Answer (score 1):

I verified the answer above and it works well. However to avoid making  the change too generic thus impacting every instance of `md-tabs` and also to avoid the need for `!important`, qualify the CSS class with a custom parent container ID or class.

Also if you want to affect only height then modify only `padding-top` such as:

```
#myTabsContainerParent .md-pagination-wrapper {
    height: 30px;
}
#myTabsContainerParent .md-tab-item {
    padding-top: 5px;
}
```